# Why didn't Hayase's Nokker control her like other Nokkers did with other humans?

Tags: to-your-eternity

All other Nokkers which attacked humans controlled them. But Why Hayase's Nokker didn't, instead it coexisted with her. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's implied that this specific Nokker was different from the rest of it's species for some unexplained reason (given that it appears to work against the other Nokkers in one case), and developed a desire to follow and aid Fushi. This lines up with Hayase's goals and it likely decided it could achieve that goal more effectively by coexisting with her (and her lineage).

Answer (score 0):

I think it was ironically afraid of death and wanted to develop individual personality. Hayase offered shared immortality. At least that's my head canon cause it just doesn't tell us why. What makes me think this is what the Nokker says in episode 14 of season 2 at 14:53

"I don't know what will happen to me when I leave here. Everything I've built up until now might be erased. I'm scared."